# How to call a specific instance of a service from another service in Angular?

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, service, angular-services, angular-components

So I have a component "motions" that executes a **MotionService** after a button is clicked with some user input. Then this service needs to pass the data to **the specific CaucusService** instance of the debateComponent (lets call it service A) or the CaucusService instance B of the DiscussComponent depending on the input. 
However, it seems that so far I have a new instance of the CaucusService in the MotionService.
debateComponent and DiscussComponent need different instances of the CaucusService, so I have provided it in each @Component

Basically, my MotionService needs to pass data to A or to B given a certain user input
How should I approach this problem?

Comment: Can you provide a stackblitz for illustrate your problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import { Injectable, Injector } from '@angular/core';
import { FirstService } from './first.service';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})

export class SecondService {

    static firstService = new FirstService();

    getFieldFromFirst() {
        const field = SortingService.fileService.getField();
        console.log(field);
    }
}
```

try by this way

Comment: But if you use a "new" operator you don't get the benefit of dependency injection

Comment: Yes, but if the fields or methods do not change in the FirstService, then the simplest solution is this.

Comment: Or, as in the documentation, you can remove "{providedIn: 'root'}" and import the services into app.module and add to providers array.

Answer (score 6):

You can specify the exact instance of the Service in 2 ways:

### Easy - Make it a singleton service

Simply adding the `providedIn: 'root'` statement to the service's declaration will ensure there is only 1 instance of that service, which means anywhere you use it will be the same instance.

```js
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CaucusService {}
```

### Hard - Use injection tokens

This is a bit more complicated, but allows for multiple instances to exist and be referenced where needed. There's information about how to do this in the angular documentation.

- https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-in-action
- https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-providers#non-class-dependencies
- https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection#dependency-injection-tokens

### General advice

It's much easier to deal with ***stateless services*** than it is to deal with services that contain state of some sort. So try and pass the state in, from the components, this will allow you to test the services much easier too.

Answer (score 0):

The approach should be something like this
Create instance of service at module level for the data you want to share between components.

Create sepate services for component level use which will contain just component date

I.e A And B Services at modules level for sharing between services 
A1 and B1 component level services which contain component specific data.